# Apache .htaccess lowercase part of the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Is there a way to redirect an url to it's lowercase version (only part of it though) using .htaccess ?

This http://siteaddress.com/Page/**Some-Mixed-Chars-Url** to http://siteaddress.com/Page/**some-mixed-chars-url**

Thanks in advance.

Here is my .htaccess file

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi Exbury, I don't thinks it's duplicate entry.
In that question the subject is at the middle of the domain name but in my question it is a bit different.
Unfortunately I'm not very good at .htaccess files and can't translate the given answer on that question to my question as an answer.

Comment: @laroel: First You have to add this to your httpd.conf: `RewriteMap lc int:tolower`. Then paste the below code into your .htaccess: `RewriteEngine On    NEWLINE      RewriteBase /     NEWLINE     RewriteRule ^(\/Page\/)([^\/]+)$ $1${lc:$2} [L,R=301]`. Replace `NEWLINE` with linebreaks. Does it work?

Comment: Hi stribizhev,
Thanks for the answer I'll give it a go now.

Comment: Couldn't make this work. It's a shared hosting so I don't have access to httpd.conf. Is there a way to do it without httpd.conf?

Comment: @laroel - I've deleted my answer as, according to the comments on the article, it seems to be crashing servers. Unfortunately, I don't think there is any other `.htaccess`-only solution. You're probably going to have to get your PHP app to make the URI lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing this using php.

Here is the solution in Laravel.

```
Route::get('/Page/{slug}, function($slug){
    if(preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $slug)){   
        return  Redirect::to('/Page/'.strtolower($slug), 301);
    }
//other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have access to your `httpd.conf` file, you will need to ask Apache to send requests containing upper-case characters to a PHP script that will handle the redirect.

**`.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if the request contains upper-case characters:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]

# If so, pass it on to the script:
RewriteRule (.*) utils/tolower.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then, in **`utils/tolower.php`**:

```
<?php

# If we have a request, process it
if (isset($_GET['request']))
{
    $url = $_GET['request'];
    unset($_GET['request']);
    $params = http_build_query($_GET);
    if (strlen($params)) $params = '?' . $params;
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . strtolower($url) . $params, true, 302);
    exit();
}

# If not, throw a 404 error
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die("Sorry, but you didn't provide a request to convert to lower-case.");
```

To make the redirect permanent, change `302` to `301` in the `header()` method.